# Reading UDP packets containing JPG video frames with python

Tags: python-3.x, udp, video-streaming, jpeg, mjpeg

I've got a cheap drone and I'm trying to read with Python the video stream coming from it.
The drone communicates via UDP protocol, and by using wireshark I see it sends jpeg frames (starts with FFD8 and finishes with FFD9).
Each frame is transmitted across multiple packets, each carrying a data payload of 1472 bytes. The final packet linked to a specific frame, which contains the remaining data, has a payload of less than 1472 bytes.

example of a typical frame sent over multiple packets (showing just the payload):

packet_1: `f8000104ffd8ffe0....53a521a168c504ee`
packet_2: `f80002043694d21a....3b53378ed5719327`

packet_3: `f800030495221784....b9371a6834ec5349`
packet_4: `f8000404a50d4ab5....b915d575ac0d661d`
packet_5: `f8000504ad9aeec3....a34393530ad98a36`
packet_6: `f800060468ac460d....7af2e9372a9a9d95`
packet_7: `f80007049a503248....16fa5f30d4a45731`
packet_8: `f80008042f978a7c....14fbafbd4c55c495`
packet_9: `f80009042dca65f8....ee17226029368a71`
packet_a: `f8000a04351eea68....4da1b8267152785f`
packet_b: `f8010b045053f2b4....3d0940000000ffd9` # here last payload contains 201 bytes

You can see clearly that every payload is sent with a 4 byte (or 8 hexstring characters) header that relates to the order of the packets regarding the jpg data and the frame number.

I tried to read the data in a lot of different ways but no matter what I do I get a very poor image quality that barely resembles what the drone is actually looking at. Important to say that when using the app that comes with the drone the footage is clear and with no latency.

**some code I used in my last iteration:**

(context: I recorded some packets coming from the drone and saved it in a pickle file as a list of hexstring representing the packet payload)

```
import pickle

with open("packets_data.pkl", "+br") as f:
    packet_list = pickle.load(f)


frame = ""
for i, pckt in enumerate(packet_list):
    print(f"{pckt[:16]}....{pckt[-16:]}", end="  ")
    frame += pckt[8:] # removing the 4 byte header from every packet
    if len(pckt) < 2944: # less than 1472 bytes is the last packet in the frame
        print(f"frame end. last packet len: {len(pckt)}, i: {i}")
        with open(f"frames/my_frame_{i}.jpg", "+wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes.fromhex(frame))
            frame = ""
    
    print()
```

The result is jpeg images that look horrible, for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuZUA.jpg)

link to packets representing a frame: https://file.io/kM9MdfqYlfSy (this can be downloaded only once)

Comment: The _"create a pickle file"_ step might be corrupting your JPEG data. As a test... (1) From each packet data, just remove the starting 4 bytes (or 8 chars of hex), (2) then If you extract and join from the first FFD8 up to first FFD9 then you should get a valid test picture. Or else share a link (zip file?) to one frame's packet data for testing..

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I started by trying this without the pickle file (which is mainly for convenience) but unfortunately I get the same results.

Added to my question a link to a pcapng file (wireshark file) which contains packets representing a whole frame.

If you have some time to go over it I would very much appreciate it!
I've pretty much explored everything I can, it seems the drone is offsetting some bytes which causes this corruption and to be able to decrypt it I need to see the app source code (rcfpvpro in app store or play store)

Comment: Hi. Your link says "File deleted". Does it auto-delete on any first download? If yes, then I think someone else is checking out the download files. Why not just make the example file open to public until you get a working solution?

Comment: PS: If needed to be private then send a download link to my mail: valerio_charles@yahoo.com

Comment: I didn't see an option for uploading files over here, just images, so tried out that website which I can see didn't work as I hoped..
Anyway I'm sending it to your email in the meantime. Thanks!